# Алгоритмы транспонирования матриц

Tags: c#, алгоритм

Есть ли какой-нибудь другой способ транспонирования квадратной матрицы?

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
    {
        tmp = a[i, j];
        a[i, j] = a[j, i];
        a[j, i] = tmp;
    }
}
```

Comment: Зачем другой способ? Этот метод не работает, что ли?

Comment: работает, но нужен другой

Comment: А почему нужен другой, если работает? В чем проблема?

Comment: Паучье чутьё подсказывает мне, что это учебное задание, так что необходимость обусловлена лишь желанием левой пятки преподавателя.

Comment: Потому что без проблем жить скучно :)

Comment: @fori1ton нет, ошибаетесь

Comment: Тогда прсветите нас, в чём необходимость другого способа транспонирования матрицы. Производительность не устраивает? Или потребление памяти? Или, может, сложность реализации?

Comment: @fori1ton это все не важно, просто для общего развития так сказать

Comment: Предлагаю погуглить `cache conscious matrix transpose` - можно найти ещё несколько хитрых алгоритмов. Готовых исходников нет.

Comment: Удивительно, что никто не сказал, что алгоритм корректен только для симметричной матрицы, для несимметричной он работает неверно. Ну, я тут сделал предположение, что индекс раскладывается в линейный row*colCount + col

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно изменить алгоритм таким образом:

- Начинать `i = 1` вместо `i = 0`
- Использовать [обмена при помощи исключающего ИЛИ](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D0%B8_%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%98%D0%9B%D0%98) вместо обычного обмена

Зачем изменить алгоритм так? Не знаю, но раз вы хотите другой способ, вот вам:

```
for (int i = 1; i < N; i++)
{
  for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
  {
    a[i, j] ^= a[j, i];
    a[j, i] ^= a[i, j];
    a[i, j] ^= a[j, i];
  }
}
```

Comment: Тут скорее другой способ обмена элементов - сам же алгоритм транспонирования остался тем же.

Comment: Да да, я согласен, это просто глупый ответ на глупый вопрос.

Answer (score 10):

Let the izvrat begin!

```
class Matrix<T>
{
    T[,] payload;
    bool isTransposed = false;

    public Matrix(int n) : this(n, n) { }
    public Matrix(int m, int n) { payload = new T[m, n]; }

    // это вызовется, если кто-то обратится к матрице по индексу:
    // Matrix<int> m = new Matrix<int>(5);
    // m[0, 2] = 42;  // <- здесь
    public T this[int i, int j]
    {
        // если стоит флаг, что матрица транспонирована, меняем местами индексы:
        get { return isTransposed ? payload[j, i] : payload[i, j]; }
        set { if (isTransposed) payload[j, i] = value; else payload[i, j] = value; }
    }

    public void Transpose() { isTransposed = !isTransposed; }
}
```

Обменяли скорость транспозиции на скорость доступа.

Comment: А можно пару коментариев на тему как это работает, чтобы было легче разобраться?  Думаю многим это не сразу будет ясно.

Comment: @koks_rs: добавил

Comment: Интересный подход.

Comment: @avp: [one more level of indirection](http://csharpindepth.com/Files/DevDays09/Image006.jpg)

Comment: последний комментарий в тему, если добавить ещё один уровень, то можно от сравнений избавиться, тогда и производительность страдать не будет

Comment: @ixSci: Напишете ещё один вариант?

Comment: @VladD, добавил

Answer (score 9):

Ненормальное программирование<sup>1</sup> на C#? Их есть у меня! Встречайте - транспонирование матрицы в функциональном стиле.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace Main
{
    static class MyLinqExtensions
    {
        public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Batch<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, int batchSize)
        {
            using(var enumerator = source.GetEnumerator())
            {
                while(enumerator.MoveNext())
                {
                    yield return YieldBatchElements(enumerator, batchSize - 1);
                }   
            }
        }

        private static IEnumerable<T> YieldBatchElements<T>(IEnumerator<T> source, int batchSize)
        {
            yield return source.Current;
            for(int i = 0; i < batchSize && source.MoveNext(); i++)
            {
                yield return source.Current;
            }
        }

        public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> ZipMany<T>(this IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> enumerables)
        {
            return enumerables.Select(inner => inner.Select((s, i) => new {s, i}))
                              .SelectMany(a => a.ToList())
                              .GroupBy(a => a.i, a => a.s)
                              .Select(a => a.ToList()).ToList();
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var matrix = new[,]
            {
                {1, 2},
                {3, 4},
                {5, 6},
                {7, 8},
                {9, 0}
            };

            var transposedMatrix = matrix.Cast<int>()
                                         .Batch(matrix.GetLength(1))
                                         .ZipMany()
                                         .Select(xs => xs.ToList())
                                         .ToList();

            foreach(var row in transposedMatrix)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", row.Select(e => e.ToString())));
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Самый короткий способ транспонировать матрицу - вызвать функцию `zip` для списка строк. На Python это занимает одну строку:

```
In [1]: matrix = [
   ...:     [1, 2],
   ...:     [3, 4],
   ...:     [5, 6],
   ...:     [7, 8],
   ...:     [9, 0]
   ...: ]

In [2]: zip(*matrix)
Out[2]: <zip at 0x7f0b71191448>

In [3]: list(zip(*matrix))
Out[3]: [(1, 3, 5, 7, 9), (2, 4, 6, 8, 0)]
```

Но в случае с C# мы сталкиваемся с рядом проблем:

1. Исходная матрица представлена в виде 2D массива, а они не поддерживают построчную обработку, тем более через LINQ
2. Функция `Zip` может свести только два списка.

Это значит, что пришло время несколько разнообразить стандартные LINQ расширения:

1. Вводим расширение, которое преобразует `int[,]` в `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>>`. Код достаточно простой - используется дополнительная функция, которая для каждого переданного объекта `IEnumerator<T>` отсчитывает нужное количетство элементов. Осталось вызвать ее для переданного объекта `IEnumerable<T>`, пока он не опустеет. Данный код взят из [этого](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13710023/1532460) ответа.
2. Вводим расширение `ZipMany`, которое будет зипповать все переданные перечисления. Реализация также достаточно примитивна - каждый элемент каждой строки ассоциируется с его порядковым номером, а затем все эти элементы группируются по их порядковым номерам. Данный код взят из [этого](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17977055/1532460) ответа.

Осталось только вызвать их для нашего массива. Вызов `Cast<int>` необходим, потому что многомерные массивы не могут работать с LINQ напрямую.

---

<sup>1</sup>: В общем случае, ФП на C# выглядит красиво. Но в данном случае нам пришлось написать кучу вспомогательного кода, из-за того, что .NET не предоставляет нужного нам функцонала. Поэтому в данном случае, императивный подход выглядит лучше, я уж молчу про бейнчмарки.

Comment: +1 Это хитрее моего ответа)

Comment: В чем практическая задача ?

Comment: Задача поста - показать альтернативное решение задачи транспонирования матрицы, сравнив, заодно, реализацию на C# и Python.

Comment: По поводу гадости - FP он такой. Потом даже нравится начинает. А всякая императивщина отдает душком.

Comment: @soon: Но всё же, проблема в ретроградских квадратных массивах. Если бы хотя бы взять jagged array, было бы как в Питоне: `matrix.MultiZip(seq => seq.ToArray()).ToArray()`.

Comment: (с вот таким `MultiZip`: http://pastebin.com/9T8hQKmM)

Comment: @VladD, согласен, но у ОП были именно 2D, поэтому не хотел отходить от исходных данных. В итоге, все равно к ним и сводится через `Batch`. Ваша реализация `MultiZip` нравится, но несколько смущает, что `en` меняет состояние.

Comment: @soon: Именно для этого пришлось сбоксировать, кстати.

Answer (score 6):

А можно сделать *параллельный* (на threads) вариант. Немного не в тему, поскольку на Си (GNU), но коду  автора в вопросе в чем-то соответствует -)

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <string.h>

#define SWAP(p1,p2) ({typeof(*p1) *_p1 = (p1), *_p2 = (p2), t = *_p1;   \
      *_p1 = *_p2; *_p2 = t;})
#define MEMDUP(p) (memcpy(malloc(sizeof(p)), &p, sizeof(p)))

struct arg {
  int *base;
  int dim;
  int row;
};

// так в соответствии с pthreads API должна оформляться функция, запускаемая в потоке
void *
trow (void *a)
{
  struct arg *pa = (typeof(pa))a;
  int i = pa->row, j;

  // получили строку, транспонируем ее хвост за диагональю
  for (j = i + 1; j < pa->dim; j++)
    SWAP(pa->base + pa->dim * i + j, pa->base + pa->dim * j + i);

  free(a);
  return 0;
}

void
ptrans (int n, int a[n][n])  // gcc позволяет передавать матрицы таким образом
{
  pthread_t tid[n - 1];
  struct arg arg = {&a[0][0], n, 0};

  // очевидно, что последнюю строку из 1-го элемента можно не трогать
  for (arg.row = 0; arg.row < n - 1; arg.row++)
    pthread_create(tid + arg.row, 0, trow, MEMDUP(arg));

  --n;
  while (n--)
    pthread_join(tid[n], 0);

}
```

При желании с помощью макросов это легко можно привести к template-виду  для заданного (скалярного?) типа.

Answer (score 6):

По мотивам ответа от @VladD, только без лишней проверки.

Сначала добавим несколько вспомогательных классов:

```
interface IAccessor<T>
{
    T this[int i, int j] { get; set; }
}

class DirectAccessor<T> : IAccessor<T>
{
    public DirectAccessor(T[,] payload)
    {
        m_Payload = payload;
    }

    public T this[int i, int j]
    {
        get { return m_Payload[i, j]; }
        set { m_Payload[i, j] = value; }
    }

    T[,] m_Payload;
}

class TransposedAccessor<T> : IAccessor<T>
{
    public TransposedAccessor(T[,] payload)
    {
        m_Payload = payload;
    }

    public T this[int i, int j]
    {
        get { return m_Payload[j, i]; }
        set { m_Payload[j, i] = value; }
    }

    T[,] m_Payload;
}
```

А теперь сам класс матрицы:

```
class Matrix<T>
{
    public Matrix(int n) : this(n, n) { }

    public Matrix(int m, int n)
    {
        m_Payload = new T[m, n];
        m_Accessor = new DirectAccessor<T>(m_Payload);
    }

    public T this[int i, int j]
    {
        get { return m_Accessor[i, j]; }
        set { m_Accessor[i, j] = value; }
    }

    public void Transpose()
    {
        if(m_Accessor is DirectAccessor<T>)
            m_Accessor = new TransposedAccessor<T>(m_Payload);
        else
            m_Accessor = new DirectAccessor<T>(m_Payload);

    }

    private IAccessor<T> m_Accessor;
    private T[,] m_Payload;
}
```

---

И ещё один вариант класса матрицы:

```
class Matrix<T>
{
    public Matrix(int n) : this(n, n) { }

    public Matrix(int m, int n)
    {
        var payload = new T[m, n];
        m_ActiveAccessor = new DirectAccessor<T>(payload);
        m_PassiveAccessor = new TransposedAccessor<T>(payload);
    }

    public T this[int i, int j]
    {
        get { return m_ActiveAccessor[i, j]; }
        set { m_ActiveAccessor[i, j] = value; }
    }

    public void Transpose()
    {
        var tmp = m_ActiveAccessor;
        m_ActiveAccessor = m_PassiveAccessor;
        m_PassiveAccessor = tmp;

    }

    private IAccessor<T> m_ActiveAccessor;
    private IAccessor<T> m_PassiveAccessor;
}
```

Comment: Для эффективности может завести два аксессора в массиве, и помнить текущий индекс? Тогда функция Transpose будет просто `m_curr = 1 - m_curr; m_Accessor = m_Accessors[m_curr];`

Comment: @VladD, добавил похожий, но немного  другой вариант

Comment: Ага, так симпатичнее.

Answer (score 3):

Ну если немного погуглить, то можно найти к примеру такой вариант:

```
 // в шарпе эта же функция объявляется так:
 //public static unsafe void transpose(float* src, float* dst, int N, int M)
 void transpose(float *src, float *dst, const int N, const int M) {

    for(int n = 0; n<N*M; n++) {
        int i = n/N;
        int j = n%N;
        dst[n] = src[M*j + i];
    }

 }
```

В этом примере сначала нужно выравнять матрицы и потом рабоать с указателями. Таким образом мы не двигаем данные туда-сюда, а лишь указатели. Что должно давать серьезный прирост в производительности.

**EDIT:**
Но как показала практика, такой вариант требует слишком много времени на математические оперции.  В результате выполняется примерно в 2 раза дольше.

Comment: Вопрос по C#, а не C/C++

Comment: @ixSci, ну автор же не ищет легких путей. А шарпе с укателями тоже можно работать. Правда не знаю даст ли это что-то.

Comment: Если помню правильно, в C# указатели не работают без блока `unsafe`.

Comment: Раз уж мы пытаемся экономить на спичках, давайте прикинем, насколько просядет производительность благодаря использованию деления и умножения в каждой итерации для нахождения адресов элементов матрицы. Ещё подумаем над увеличением количества итераций в 2 раза по сравнению с исходным вариантом. Ну, и не забудем увеличение потребления памяти в 2 раза: в исходном варианте транспонирование осуществлялось над исходной матрицей, без копирования.

Comment: Вот, собственно, бенчмарки. Делаем транспонирование квадратной матрицы 1000x1000 float'ов столько раз, сколько позволит пятисекундный лимит на время выполнения в ideone. По результату 10 запусков каждой из реализаций, получаем, что [ваша](http://ideone.com/6GCpUT) почти в полтора раза медленнее [наивной](http://ideone.com/6X5U0p) (350 транспонирований за 5 секунд против 510). Конечно, это нужно запускать не на ideone, и гораздо большее число раз, чем 500, но для грубых оценок сойдёт. К сожалению, у меня нет под рукой компилятора C, так что предлагаю кому-нибудь перепроверить мои выкладки.

Comment: @fori1ton, ваша реализация некорректна. Алгоритм предпологает получить на вход одмерный массив. Вы туда передали двухмерный. Вообще странно что это выполнилось там, у меня к примеру постоянный вылет за пределы массива на стационарном компе. Плюс передача не инициализированного массива в фунцию.

Comment: @koks_rs, возможно, вы имели ввиду, что моя реализация вашего алгоритма некорректна? Я исправил. Значительных изменений в производительности не замечено, скорее наоборот, число итераций, стабильно укладывающихся в 5 секунд, снизилось до 320. Насчёт вылетов: для проверки я упростил задачу до транспонирования _квадратных_ матриц, как, собственно, это сделал ТС. Обратите внимание, его код вылетит на прямоугольной матрице.

Comment: @fori1ton,  перепроверил с замерами вызова времени выполнения именно функций без инициализации. На 500 вызовов исходный вариант требует около 2х сек, мой же вариант выполняется около 5сек.

Comment: Здесь используется другой способ представления матрицы - алгоритм же остался тем же.

Answer (score 2):

Иммутабельный вариант:

```
var newMatrix = new int[N, N];

for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
    {
        newMatrix[i, j] = a[j, i];
    }
}

// по желанию 
a = newMatrix;
```

Если чуть причесать:

```
static int[,] Transpose(int[,] matrix)
{
    if (matrix.GetUpperBound(0) != matrix.GetUpperBound(1))
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Non-square matrix");
    }

    if (matrix.GetLowerBound(0) != 0 || matrix.GetLowerBound(1) != 0)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Non-zero-based matrix");
    }

    int N = matrix.GetUpperBound(0) + 1;

    var newMatrix = new int[N, N];

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
        {
            newMatrix[i, j] = matrix[j, i];
        }
    }

    return newMatrix;
}

// .....
// вызов:
a = Transpose(a);
```