# Как реверснуть двумерный массив?

Tags: c#, массивы

Нужно реверснуть двумерный массив по такому принципу.

Исходный массив:

```
[0, 1, 2]
[3, 4, 5]
[6, 7, 8]
```

Реверснутый массив:

```
[8, 7, 6]
[5, 4, 3]
[2, 1, 0]
```

Получилось его реверснуть только для первой и последней строки, то есть так:

```
[8, 7, 6]
[3, 4, 5]
[2, 1, 0]
```

Сам код алгоритма:

```
static int[,] ReverseArr(int[,] SourceArray)
        { 
            int rows = SourceArray.GetUpperBound(0) + 1;
            int columns = SourceArray.GetUpperBound(1) + 1;

            int temp = 0;

            for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++)
            {
                temp = SourceArray[0, j];

                SourceArray[0, j] = SourceArray[rows - 1, columns - j - 1];

                SourceArray[rows - 1, columns - j - 1] = temp;
            }

            return SourceArray;
        }
```

А как обращаться к другим строкам массива?
Пытался делать через двойной for, но на других проходах массив возвращался в исходное состояние, а использовать сторонние библиотеки нельзя, только `System`, только хардкор

Есть идея костыльнуть и записать двумерный массив в массив `int[][]` и уже с помощью `Array.Reverse()` перевернуть, но это костыль :(

Comment: Это учебное задание? Вам способами для новичика, или любой способ подойдет?

Comment: @aepot Да. Подойдет любым способом, но без использования сторонних библиотек

Comment: @aepot спасибо)

Comment: Связанный вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/432750/218063

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Есть 2 способа

Первый способ обычный цикл в цикле по каждому элементу массива

```cs
static int[,] ReverseMatrix(int[,] array)
{
    int rows = array.GetLength(0);
    int columns = array.GetLength(1);
    int[,] result = new int[rows, columns];
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++)
        {
            result[rows - i - 1, columns - j - 1] = array[i, j];
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Второй способ для более продвинутых разработчиков с использованием Linq и `Buffer.BlockCopy`.

```cs
static int[,] ReverseMatrix(int[,] array)
{
    int rows = array.GetLength(0);
    int columns = array.GetLength(1);
    int[,] result = new int[rows, columns];
    Buffer.BlockCopy(array.Cast<int>().Reverse().ToArray(), 0, result, 0, rows * columns * sizeof(int));
    return result;
}
```

Конкретно в этой реализации оба способа работать будут примерно с одинаковой скоростью.

---

Для знатоков из разряда "кто быстрее".

```cs
static unsafe void ReverseMatrixInMemory<T>(T[,] array) where T : unmanaged
{
    fixed (T* ptr = array)
        new Span<T>(ptr, array.Length).Reverse();
}
```

Для тех, кому стало интересно, вот [ссылка](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/MemoryExtensions.cs#L1106) на `Span<T>.Reverse()`. Ходят слухи, что оно раза в полтора быстрее, чем `Array.Reverse()` даже для одномерного массива, но я не проверял.

Answer (score 4):

Ещё один альтернативный вариант.

Если бы у нас был одномерный массив {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8} - мы могли бы использовать два указателя, поставив их на разные концы массива: достаточно менять местами ячейки и потихоньку сдвигать указатели друг к другу.

Что-то в духе:

```
var arr = new[] {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};

for(var i = 0; i < arr.Length / 2; i++)
{
    var j = arr.Length - i - 1;
    
    var temp = arr[j];
    arr[j] = arr[i];
    arr[i] = temp;
}
```

Ничто не мешает нам так же поступить и с двумерным массивом, нужно просто уметь преобразовывать координату одномерного массива в координаты двумерного массива, как-то так:

```
int[,] arr = new int[,]
{
    {0, 1, 2},
    {3, 4, 5},
    {6, 7, 8},
};

var size = (int)Math.Sqrt(arr.Length);

for (var i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
{
    var a = i / size;
    var b = i % size;
    Console.WriteLine(arr[a, b]);
}
```

Ну и в итоге приходим к какому-то такому алгоритму:

```
static int[,] ReverseMatrix(int[,] arr)
{
    var size = arr.GetLength(1);
    for(var i = 0; i < arr.Length / 2; i++)
    {
        var i1 = arr.Length - i - 1;
        
        var temp = arr[ i1 / size, i1 % size ];
        arr[i1 / size, i1 % size] = arr[i / size, i % size];
        arr[i / size, i % size] = temp;
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Результат отработки на исходных данных как в вопросе:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

PS Надо сказать, что изначально мне вообще в голову пришёл ещё один алгоритм: можно просто инвертировать строки и столбцы (ну или столбцы, а потом строки), но это какой-то неспортивный алгоритм -- так чисто, рассказать преподавателю, какие ещё возможны варианты.

Comment: эх, опередили [меня](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XBiiw.png) :)

Comment: но O(n) будет одинаковым в обоих вариантах

Comment: @tym32167 О, а я всё пытаюсь вспомнить, как size считается без корня. )

Comment: вам нужен не size, а количество колонок, это будет `source.GetLength(1)`. Там же не квадрантая матрица, а просто прямоугольная.

Comment: Почему n² то? Сложность такая же как и у вас. Ну а по поводу последнего абзаца, где-то здесь уже был похожий топик с ответом от Влада, делаем обёртку над массивом и добавляем флаг IsReversed, а индексатор реализуем с учётом этого флага. Всё. Вся операция реверса — одно действие `IsReversed = !IsReversed`

Comment: Довольно интересный топик, кстати: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/432750/218063